# Can have had instead of may have had

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect

Is it correct if somebody uses **"can have had"** instead of **"may have had"**?

- I can have called him yesterday, but I don't remember speaking to him.
- She can have done it but without proof we can't say for sure.

Does changing it from **Past Perfect** to **Pluperfect** change the meaning?

- I could have called him yesterday, but I don't remember speaking to him.
- She could have done it but without proof we can't say for sure.

Do **"would"** and **"should"** of the *"Pluperfect"* have similar in *"Past Perfect"*? While **may** (Past perfect) = **might** (Pluperfect) and **can** (Past perfect) = **could** (Pluperfect), what do **would** (Pluperfect) and **should** (Pluperfect) equal?

Comment: Aren't pluperfect and past perfect the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

```
I can't do that today

I couldn't do that when I was a kid
```

Here the tenses are different, repsectively present and simple past.
However **Pluperfect = Past Perfect**

**can't have done** and **couldn't have done** are both in the same tense but the modals are different.

---

You are asking about the epistemic modality, that is the degree of confidence.

*Increasing order of uncertainty*

> He must have done that / He may have done that / He might have done that

**can have done** is not grammatical, you should use **must have done** instead.
However in a negative sentence it is fine:

> He can't have done that / He may not have done that / He might not have done that

The difference between **can't have done** and **couldn't have done** is that the latter is about something we are sure of,  whereas the former is about ability/possiblilty of an event that didn't happen.

Compare

> She might have used the car

That's uncertain, I don't know if she did

> She could have used the car

It was possible for her to use the car, but she didn't

*Note: In some cases people use **could have** to mean **may have**/**might have** with **could have***

Lastly **Should** and **Would** don't have other forms